# Directx10: MSAA max texture size?

Tags: directx, direct2d, directx-10

In DirectX 10, how do I find out the maximum texture size for a MSAA texture for a given sample count/quality?

I'm trying to render some geometry using Direct2D rendering to a Direct3D MSAA surface but for large textures (~5000x2500) I get strange results. Everything gets rendered fine if the MSAA sample count is reduced from 8 to 4. I don't get any errors when creating the textures or when rendering.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ID3D10Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check for support.

You can also use the CAPS viewer tool that installs with the SDK.

Also check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc627090(v=vs.85).aspx for supported formats and their target uses. (Note the page table displays incorrectly. Copy and paste the table to see all the columns.)